# with PCM-16 no speech sound

Tags: speech-processing, speech, pcm

I am trying to create a synthethic speech dataset. A quick overview of the my process is:

1. read wav
2. apply stft
3. do some stuff (ex. add noise, etc.)
4. apply istft
5. write wav

Now, the .wav file that I am reading is 8kHz and its format is PCM-16. But when I apply stft and revert it back to its original form it is converted to an array of Float32s.
And when I write it as it is (Array of Float32s) everything is fine but the format (yes I know, that it should be Signed Int16 for PCM.) When I listen the .wav file I can hear the speech.

On the other hand, when I convert the Array of Float32s to Int16 all speech data is lost but I can write it as PCM 16 Signed Int.

Why is this happening ? Could someone help ?

Best Regards

Comment: You don't specify which library or tool you used to write the wav file, but some libraries might do the conversion for you (matlab accept floats and doubles), this might be the reason why you can hear something using floats (you just need to make sure it's in a valid range -1.0 to 1.0).  To convert to int16 you should normalize and scale your data, if you only do a casting int16(value) and the value is in the range -1.0 to 1.0 you'll get zero for almost all the data

Comment: no, it should not necessarily be signed int16 for PCM. That's one possible choice only. However, we can't debug code that we're not seeing - also, are you sure this is a signal processing issue? Sounds more like an issue with the library you use to read or write files.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comments. To briefly summarize, I use Julia programming language and WAV.jl package for reading and writing .wav files. I can specify the format as PCM which is called `native` inside the package. In order to write it as PCM-16 need to convert the data for which I use casting operation as @Hkxs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I will post the code. Mean while, I will also try to do the same operations on MATLAB. By the way, after posting the O.P. I tried to do convolution operation on the same data. And write it to .wav file. And I think that MATLAB also converts to PCM16 by default. And again I hear no speech sound. But this might also be related with convolution operation.

Comment: yeah, this doesn't sound like a signal processing, but a programming problem...